# How to make a example about http with synchronous in Angular2?

Tags: angular

How to make a example about http with synchronous in Angular2?

I tried as below, in component:

```
getAllAddress(){
    this.addressService.getAllAddress().then(`enter code here`
            result => {
                this.data = result.list;
                this.onChangeTable(this.config, null);
                console.log('FIRST');
            }
        );
    console.log('LAST');
}
```

In service:

```
public getAllAddress(){
    return this.__http.get('LOCATION')
    .map((res) => {
    return res.json()
    })
    .toPromise();
}
```

But the console show log is 'LAST' before 'FIRST'.

Comment: Angular2 http doesn't support synchronous requests. What's the purpose anyway? You don't need to use Angular2's `Http` if you really need a sync request.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can't load data synchronously in the browser since the underlying API (`XMLHttpRequest`) is asynchronous.

That being said, you could preload data if your data are reference ones or configuration ones. In this case, you could leverage the `APP_INITIALIZER` service. The application will wait for the returned promise to be resolved before actually starting.

Here is a sample:

```
provide(APP_INITIALIZER, {
  useFactory: (service:GlobalService) => () => service.load(),
  deps:[GlobalService, HTTP_PROVIDERS], multi: true
})
```

The `load` method would like something like that:

```
load():Promise<Site> {
  var promise = this.http.get('config.json').map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
  promise.then(config => this.devServer = config.devServer);
  return promise;
}
```

Then you can directly use the `devServer` (synchronously)...